# Cannot invalidate template cache (by element) on entries.onDeleteEntry

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I'm trying to do `craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElementId` on `entries.onDeleteEntry`, unsuccessfully.

The event listener is working, but the caches don't get invalidated.

Here's the code:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('entries.onSaveEntry', function($event) {
        $this->clearEntryCache($event);
    });

    craft()->on('entries.onDeleteEntry', function($event) {
        $this->clearEntryCache($event);
    });

}

public function clearEntryCache(Event $event) {
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    craft()->templateCache->deleteCachesByElementId($entry->id, true);
}
```

- `entries.onSaveEntry` works perfectly.
- Instead of run `deleteCachesByElementId`, if I `deleteAllCaches`, it works (but I don't want to do this)
- I've also tried `entries.onBeforeDeleteEntry` with no luck.
- I've tried deleting from the entry, and from the entry listing (bulk delete) screen.

On the surface it seems maybe it isn't working because by the time `deleteCachesByElementId`, the element is already deleted...though it still seems there should be a way to delete that cache with the elementId reference.

Comment: Do you have stuck tasks, by chance? (http://buildwithcraft.com/help/stuck-tasks) A difference between `deleteCachesByElementId` and `deleteAllCaches` is that the former regulates the bulk of it's work to a task to run.

Comment: No stuck tasks (craft_tasks is empty)

Comment: Just double checked - no errors in logs

Comment: By the time the `onDeleteEntry` event is raised, then the entry is already deleted and it's caches should already be nuked.  That's not what you're seeing? Maybe you've got some other caching going on (browser/Varnish/PHP opcache/etc.)?

Comment: Ah yes - I see that in ElementsService.php:1669...Interesting, I see saveElement does that too...so now I'm wondering why I had to manually do that.

So - keep in mind this is template output, but coming from a plugin _not_ a craft.entries tag.

Comment: Looking into the DB now - I see my cached template in craft_templatecaches, but _nothing_ in craft_templatecachelements. So it seems that's likely the source of my problem?

So perhaps the only reason my saveElement clearing is working is because I'm passing true to the cacheCriteria arg

So I guess I need to find out how to get my elements into the templatecacheelements table

Comment: hmmm as easy as craft()->templateCache->includeElementInTemplateCaches ? Trying now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's what did it:
In my plugin, I had to manually call:

```
        craft()->templateCache->includeElementInTemplateCaches($entry->id);
```

With that, I didn't need had any of my event listeners in place.

Interesting that things seem to be inserted into craft_templatecachecriteria automatically, but not into craft_templatecacheelements...Perhaps that is bug?